# Unallocated space partition to Ubuntu Partition

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, windows-7, gparted

I have a dual boot machine (Win 7 and Ubuntu 14.04). My situation is this one:

[image]

sda1 and sda2 are of Windows

sda6 is my ubuntu partition. I would like to extend this one. I searched on the internet but all the situations look a bit different from mine and I am not able to figure out how to do it properly.

Thanks a lot,
Fab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can move and extend system partitions with GParted from a [live system](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/try-ubuntu-before-you-install):

1. Unmount and swap off all partitions with a key symbol in front of them (if any) through the context menu.
2. Grow the extended partition (sda4) to include the unallocated space in front of it.
3. Move and resize the logical partitions (sda5 and sda6) to your liking.
4. Commit the changes and wait for their completion.

**Warning:** There's a risk that the content of the resized file systems is corrupted in the process. For moving and growing operations it's rather low, but you should back up the important data on those partitions nonetheless. Even if the software and hardware were flawless a sudden power outage or battery failure may interrupt the process and leave the data in an inconsistent state.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you'll be able to 'extend it' due to it's position on the drive, at least in the classical sense. Regardless of your decision after the fact, you will have to format the unallocated space, ideally with ext4 since that is what you used for your Ubuntu install partition. You will then be able to mount the new space. If your Ubuntu install was implemented with LVM, you can then go in and add your newly formatted space to the logical volume group. If you didn't set up LVM when you installed your Ubuntu OS, you may still be able to do so (it's been a while since I've had to go through this process). Again, you don't necessarily have to add it to the volume group if you just want to use it for storage or some similar purpose. I've included links to get you started - hope that helps.

[Ubuntu LVM Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Lvm)

[Installing a new hard drive](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallingANewHardDrive)

Comment: I disagree. It's possible to resize extended partitions and the logical partitions within (particularly with GParted) and it has been done. The system of the question author obviously doesn't use LVM.

Comment: The point I was making was that it won't be simple 'drag the slider' operation - in either the solution you proposed or the one that I proposed, there would be steps involved. Additionally, it's not too late to implement LVM, and doing so would solve most future hard drive expansion issues. Truthfully, both of these answers are correct and achieve resolution to the same task.